# How to find whats in the inputstream?

Tags: java, html, spring

I want to create a small program in which the user will provide me with the url and then he/she will get the images present in that webpage. Below is the code from which I have started:

```
    URL postURL = new URL(url);
    InputStream inputStream = postURL.openStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            inputStream));
    String line;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    loggerService.log(sb.toString());
    return null;
```

It will provide me with the html of the webpage and search for the `<img>` tags. But what if the url provided to me is something like [Direct Image Link](http://s28.postimg.org/8fmfjney5/brand2.png) which contains the direct image, as it will not contain html. How to tackle this? Also, I'm eager to find out some apis that I could use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a headhless browser to retrieve the proper DOM and then start getting the images from there.

Comment: At least one hack you could try would be, look for META information tags, if they are not there you could assume it is not HTML.

Comment: Here is an answer with what I am suggesting (refer answer by kit) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602060/how-can-i-get-mime-type-of-an-inputstream-of-a-file-that-is-being-uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I think jsoup is what your looking for, at least in terms of an API. HTML parsing is made very convenient here.

You can real more about Jsoup: [here](http://jsoup.org/) 
You can find some tutorials and detailed explanation: [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsoup-tutorial)