# cq5 determine file content type or media type or mimetype

Tags: aem

I have following code to save an asset in a servler service

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = this.resolverFactory.getAdministrativeResourceResolver(null);
AssetManager assetMgr = (AssetManager)resourceResolver.adaptTo((Class)AssetManager.class);
String newFile = "/content/dam/travel/" + fileName;
assetMgr.createAsset(newFile, is, "image/jpeg", true);
```

The following line creates the asset with specified mimetype

```
assetMgr.createAsset(newFile, is, "image/jpeg", true);
```

I would like to determine the coming file content type based on stream rather than name.

Thank you,
Sri

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602060/how-can-i-get-mime-type-of-an-inputstream-of-a-file-that-is-being-uploaded